# Having the same height for datepicker and select?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I have this code using HTML, Javascript :

Here is the HTML code :

```
<input type="text" id="date1" name="date1"/>
<select name="pets" id="pet-select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
    <option value="spider">Spider</option>
    <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
</select>
```

Here is my code : https://jsfiddle.net/6egzaj3q/

But I would like to have no margin between the select and the datepicker, and also to have the same height for the datepicker and the select I mean something like this :

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojOic.png)

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap those `input` and `select` into new `div` and implement `display: flex` layout to that `div` selector and the whitespace will be removed.

```
<div style="display: flex">
  <input type="text" id="date1" name="date1" />
  <select name="pets" id="pet-select">
    <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
    <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
    <option value="spider">Spider</option>
    <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here's the working [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/vrm6b837/).